# What are data structures behind letter by letter search?

Tags: algorithm, search

Recently I've been reading some information regarding various data structures and their use in practice. I am especially interested in those that are used in searching. For example searching suggestions from Google, or searching in Windows.

If the text is fully typed something like hash table should work to find it in O(1). This is because we assume that they are already in the hash table. However, what happens, when we type in every letter and it search only based on letter 1, [1-2], [1-3] ...? Is it some kind of  suffix array or trie used in the process?

Answer (score 0):

I think this page describing "string searching" or "string matching" algorithms is what you are looking for:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm